# Matrices in MIPS

Tags: assembly, matrix, mips, mars-simulator

I am trying to write a MIPS code that asks the user to enter 9 integers for two different 3x3 matrices. The output should provide the product of the matrices. I am extremely new to MIPS, so any help as to where I might be going wrong with the code would be extremely helpful!

```
.data
promptA: .asciiz "\n\nEnter a number for Matrix A: "
promptB: .asciiz "\n\nEnter a number for Matrix B: "
promptC: .asciiz "\n\nThis is Matrix C: "
space:   .asciiz " "
newline: .asciiz "\n"
matrixA: .word 1, 2, 3
matrixB: .word 4, 5, 6
matrixC: .word 7, 8, 9

.text
main:

li $t0, 0                               # initialize counter to keep track
li $t1, 8                               # loading 9 to keep track

la $t2, matrixA                         # load base address of MatrixA into $t2
la $t3, matrixB                         # load base address of MatrixB into $t3

# reading in matrixA
read_int:
bgt $t0, $t1, to_Multiply               # if counter is greater than 8, stop reading values into arrayA

li $v0, 4                               # system call code for printing a string
la $a0, promptA                         # loading address of string into $a0
syscall

li $v0, 5                               # code for reading an integer
syscall                                 # reads integer into $v0
move $t5, $v0                           #integer gets moved to $t5
sw $t5, 0($t2)                          # saves integer into MatrixA[$t2]

# reading in matrixB
li $v0, 4                               #system call code for printing a string
la $a0, promptB                         #loading address of string into $a0
syscall

li $v0, 5                               # code for reading an integer
syscall                                 # reads integer into $v0
move $t6, $v0                           #integers gets moved to $t6
sw $t6, 0($t3)                          # saves integer into MatrixB[$t3]


addi $t2, $t2, 4                        # incrementing address of MatrixA
addi $t3, $t3, 4                        # incrementing address of MatrixB
addi $t0, $t0, 1                        # incrementing looper counter
j read_int

to_Multiply:
addi $t0, $zero, 8
addi $t2, $zero, -32
addi $t3, $zero, -32
j Multiply

Multiply:
mulu $s1, $t2, $t3
addi $t2, $t2, 4
addi $t3, $t3, 12
mulu $s2, $t2, $t3
addi $t2, $t2, 4
addi $t3, $t3, 12
mulu $s3, $t2, $t3
addu $s1, $s1, $s2
addu $t4, $s1, $s3
beq $t4, $t0, to_RowB           #If MatrixC is at the 3rd element jump to_RowB
beq $t4, $t0, to_RowC           #If MatrixC is at the 6th element jump to_RowC
beq $t4, $t0, print_MatrixC             #If MatrixC is at the 9th element jump print_row1
j to_RowA

to_RowA:
addi $t2, $t2, -8                       #Go back to first element in MatrixA
addi $t3, $t3, -20                      #Go to first element in second column of MatrixB
addi $t4, $t4, 4                        #Increment to next element in MatrixC
j Multiply

to_RowB:
addi $t2, $t2, 4                        #Increment to next element in MatrixA
addi $t3, $t3, -32                      #Increment to next element in MatrixB
addi $t4, $t4, 4                        #Increment to next element in MatrixC
j Multiply

to_RowC:
addi $t2, $t2, 4                        #Increment to next element in MatrixA
addi $t3, $t3, -20                      #Increment to next element in MatrixB
addi $t4, $t4, 4                        #Increment to next element in MatrixC
j Multiply


#Print MatrixC
print_MatrixC:
li $v0, 4                               #system call code for printing a string
la $a0, promptC                         #loading address of string into $a0
syscall

la $a0, matrixC                         #Load address of MatrixC into $a0
li $t0, 0                               #Initialize counter to 1st element of MatrixC
li $t1, 2                               #Initialize to 3rd element of MatrixC  to keep track of counter
j print_row1


print_row1:
beq $t0, $t1, to_row2                   #If counter equals 2 jump to_row2
lw $a0, 0($t4)                          #a0 = c1-c3
li $v0, 1                               #print integer c1-c3
syscall

li $v0, 4                               #system call to print string
la $a0, space                           #print a space between each integer
syscall

addi $t4, $t4, 4                        #Increment address of MatrixC to next element
addi $t0, $t0, 1                        #Increment counter
j print_row1


to_row2:
li $t0, 3                               #Initialize counter to 3rd element
li $t1, 5                               #Initialize counter to 5th element to keep track
addi $t4, $t4, 4                        #Increment address of MatrixC to next element

li $v0, 4                               #System call to print string
la $a0, newline                         #Go to next line
syscall
j print_row2

print_row2:
beq $t0, $t1, to_row3                   #If counter equals 5 jump to_row3
lw $a0, 0($t4)                          #a0 = c4-c6
li $v0, 1                               #print integer c4-c6
syscall

li $v0, 4                               #system call to print string
la $a0, space                           #print a space between each integer
syscall

addi $t4, $t4, 4                        #Increment address of MatrixC
addi $t0, $t0, 1                        #Increment counter
j print_row2


to_row3:
li $t0, 6                               #Initialize counter to 7th element of MatrixC
li $t1, 8                               #Initialize to 9th element of MatrixC to keep track of counter
addi $t4, $t4, 4                        #Increment address of MatrixC

li $v0, 4                               #System call to print string
la $a0, newline                         #Go to next line
syscall
j print_row3

print_row3:
beq $t0, $t1, exit                      #If counter equals the 9th element of MatrixC go to exit
lw $a0, 0($t4)                          #a0 = c7-c9
li $v0, 1                               #print integer c7-c9
syscall

li $v0, 4                               #system call to print string
la $a0, space                   #print a space between each integer
syscall

addi $t4, $t4, 4                        #Increment address of MatrixC
addi $t0, $t0, 1                        #Increment counter
j print_row3


exit:
li $v0,10
syscall
```

So far, the code allows the user to enter 9 integers for both matrices, but it does not provide any output.

Comment: Could you explain the motivation for having `t0`, `t2`, `t3` equal 8, -32 and -32 when you reach `Multiply:` for the first time? And why are there three conditional jumps with identical conditions following eachother (`beq $t4,$t0`)? I also can't find anywhere in your code where you actually multiply elements of the two matrices.

Comment: I add 8 to t0 because the multiply procedure applies to the first row of matrixC which are address element 0, 4, 8. Once matrixC reaches the third element of address 8, it then skips to the next row of matrixC. In the first row of matrixC the elements of matrixA, addresses 0, 4, and 8, get multiplied by the first column of matrixB which are addresses 0, 12, and 24. For example, C1=A1xB1 + A2xB4 + A3xB7.

Comment: So, I set t0=8 to keep track of which element matrixC is on. Then I had to set t2 and t3 back to the first elements of matrixA and matrixB after the matrices have been filled by the user. I'm assuming that once the matrices are filled the address of matrixA and matrixB are at the last element (A[9] & B[9]).

Comment: once t4=8=t0 the first row is done, so it jumps to adjust the address of all the matrices to work on the second row: C4 = A4xB1 + A5xB4 + A6xB7. I had to adjust the addresses of the matrices so the next row could be completed. The multiplication takes place in the mulitply procedure.

Comment: _"Then I had to set t2 and t3 back to the first elements of matrixA and matrixB"_. You're not subtracting 32 from `$t2` and `$t3` though; you're giving them the value -32 (`$zero + -32`). And I still don't see where you're multiplying the elements of A and B. To me it looks more like you're multiplying the addresses/offsets of the elements. And again, you've got those three `beq` instructions that don't make any sense, since the last two of them never will result in a jump.

Comment: I would need to change that to addi $t2, $t2, -32 to make t2 the address of the first element again, and do the same for t3 then, correct? Also, I need to load the elements of the address in the beginning of the multiply procedure in order to multiply the actual element at the addresses instead of multiplying the addresses? As far as the beq instructions are concerned, I'm trying to say that when t4(MatrixC) is at the 3rd element (t4=address 8=t0), then it should jump to the next row, and when t4=address 20 jump to next row, so on and so forth.

Comment: I realize how wrong I am with this code. I'm getting confused with the addresses of registers and the actual content of the registers. I'm taking a step back and reapproaching the program from a completely different view. Thank you for your help, Michael!

Comment: Check this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881233/2d-array-in-mips/18286325#18286325