# How to implement 2D array in MIPS

Tags: arrays, assembly, mips

The information that i have found on the internet for this is not explained very well. I would like to know how to go about implementing a 2-D array of double-precision floating point numbers. I would like the dimensions of the array to be variable so if I say .double 100, then I am wasting a lot of memory because that may not be the size of the array e.g. could be 5 x 5. Would I have to use the stack to solve this problem? Or how else could I go about it? Also if someone could explain how to efficiently fill the array it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is the issue you're having about dynamically allocating memory (use `sbrk` or the stack) or is it about using the memory as a 2d array (pick a row order and index accordingly as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881233/2d-array-in-mips))? These are two separate problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement any rectangular 2D array as 1D array using [row-major order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order), the only different would be is in calculating the address of the element.

For example if you have a 3×5 array of `double`'s and you want to access the element `array[x][y]`, you can calculate its address using the formula:

```
address of array[x][y] = base of array + 8 * (5 * x + y)
```

where `base of array` is the base address of `array` or `array[0][0]`, `8` is the size of an element `sizeof(double)` and `5` is the number of columns.