# Mips address out of range Runtime Exception

Tags: assembly, mips, memory-address, mars-simulator

I was trying the answer from the post [2D Array in MIPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881233/2d-array-in-mips) , which provides a complete coded solution for Row major matrix as user input.

```
    .data
read_row_matrix_prompt_p:   .asciiz "Enter an integer: "
###########################################################

.text
read_row_matrix:
        li $t3, 0               # initialize outer-loop counter to 0
    li $t2, 3
    li $t1, 3
read_row_matrix_loop_outer:
        bge $t3, $t1, read_row_matrix_loop_outer_end
        li $t4, 0               # initialize inner-loop counter to 0

read_row_matrix_loop_inner:
        bge $t4, $t2, read_row_matrix_loop_inner_end
        mul $t5, $t3, $t2       # $t5 <-- width * i
        add $t5, $t5, $t4       # $t5 <-- width * i + j
    sll $t5, $t5, 2         # $t5 <-- 2^2 * (width * i + j)
        add $t5, $t0, $t5       # $t5 <-- base address + (2^2 * (width * i + j))

        li $v0, 4               # prompt for number
        la $a0, read_row_matrix_prompt_p
        syscall

        li $v0, 5               # read a integer number
        syscall

        sw $v0, 0($t5)          # store input number into array <--- ""Error""
        addiu $t4, $t4, 1       # increment inner-loop counter
        b read_row_matrix_loop_inner    # branch unconditionally back to beginning of the inner loop

read_row_matrix_loop_inner_end:
        addiu $t3, $t3, 1       # increment outer-loop counter
        b read_row_matrix_loop_outer    # branch unconditionally back to beginning of the outer loop

read_row_matrix_loop_outer_end:
```

and I have run into the following error :

```
 line 28: Runtime exception at 0x00400048: address out of range 0x00000000
```

Similar error has been posted in many questions, but each scenario seems to be local.

I realize that #t5 would actually start from $t0 to begin with, since all the initialization make it Zero. I tried to start with **1** as well for the counters and still faced the same Error.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: `$t0` is supposed to be the base address for the array. I don't see that initialized anywhere. The array is not allocated either.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am new to Mips and have been trying to create a 2d array from user input. I came across this answer, and was learning by trial / error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this part of the code before executing the procedure helped me initialize the array and it worked fine

```
    mul $a0, $t1, $t2 #multiply to get the 2d array size and store in a0 register
    sll $a0, $a0, 2 #multiply the resulting output with 2^2 = 4 for integers address size location

    li  $v0, 9 #allocate address with memory size as in a0
    syscall
    move $t0,$v0 #resulting memory stored in t0 register
```